# how to kill a processus from an other processus?

Tags: python, time, while-loop, multiprocessing, exit

I have 2 processus here :

```
def listen() :
   while 1 :
      data = sock.recv(1024)
      ip_header = data[:20]
      ips = ip_header[-8:-4]
      source = '%i.%i.%i.%i' % (ord(ips[0]), ord(ips[1]), ord(ips[2]), ord(ips[3]))
      print 'Ping from %s' % source
```

And here:

```
def timerkill() :
   print "Launch proc2"
   print times
   time.sleep(int(times))
   print "End of proc2"
```

I try to start the second proc when the first processus found anything in "data" then while the first proc doing his job .At the end of "times" second i need to end the first processus from the second.

I don't know how to do it. If anybody can help me .

Ps : I'm sorry if my English isn't verry good.

Answer (score 1):

Add a global variable like `runProc1` and set it to `True`. Then, in the `listen` function replace `while 1` with `while runProc1==True`. In the `timerkill` function, add

```
global runProc1
runProc1 = False
```

after the `time.sleep(int(times))` line

Comment: It works but it start the second proc without knowing if the first one received anything. I don't know how to start the second proc only when the first proc received any data without breaking the loop.

Comment: @user2275322: If I get you right, you want to add a possibility to launch the second process without stopping the first process? If so, just add a variable to timerkill like `killProc1` that defaults to False and add an if to the timerkill function.